# Why does my code output me this error of ';' and ','?

Tags: c++

So, coding this, I had, and still having, this error

> Pin.cpp:14:19: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
> std::string ask(a){"

```cpp
#include <iostream>

std::string a;

std::string question()
{
    std::string ans;
    std::cout << "What do you want?\n";
    std::cout << "a) Play a game "
              << "b) Sing a song "
              << " c) Nothing\n";
    std::cout << "Enter a, b or c to choose one option:\n";
    std::cin >> ans;
    return ans;
}

std::string ask(a)
{

    if (a == "a") {
        // Here goes the game
        std::cout << "Coming soon...";
    }
    else if (a == "b") {
        std::cout << "I got 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, M's\n"
                  << "In my bank accout yeah\n"
                  << "In my bank accout yeah\n";
    }
    else if (a == "c") {

        std::cout << "See ya soon.\n";
    }
}

int main()
{

    int pin = 0;
    int tries = 1;

    std::cout << "Try # 1,"
              << "BANK\n";

    std::cout << "Enter your PIN: ";
    std::cin >> pin;
    tries++;

    while (pin != 1234 && tries <= 3) {

        std::cout << "Try "
                  << "#" << tries << ","
                  << " Enter your PIN: ";
        std::cin >> pin;
        tries++;
    }

    if (pin == 4242564) {

        std::cout << "PIN accepted!\n";
        std::cout << "You now have access.\n";
        std::string a = question();
        ask(a);
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout << "PIN not accepted.\n";
    std::cout << "Blocking acount...\n";
    std::cout << "Block sucess.\n";
}
}
```

Well, so basicly I don't know why it is happening because I think there is all the ';' and ',' in my code.

I'm new at c++ and I don't know why is this happening, thank you (btw, it's my first question here, so ignore if is anything badly tabbed).

Comment: You can't just 'do' stuff in the global space. There also seems to be a huge disconnect between those first [misplaced] lines of code and the rest of your program. Excess braces look to be an issue. Generally, indentation is a mess.

Comment: Is `std::string ask(a){` intended fo be a function? If yes it's missing the type of parameter `a` and a `return`.

Comment: Is `ask` supposed to be a function or a variable? If it's a function, it needs to return an `std::string` and you need to specify the type of the argument `a`. If it's a variable... I really don't follow what's going on with the stuff immediately after `std::string ask(a)` in that case.

Comment: you also messed up the brackets in main function

Comment: At least `#include <string>`

Comment: The error message you posted is referring to line 14 column 19 of `Pin.cpp`. However, in the code you posted, line 14 does not have a column 19. That line is only 15 characters long. Please post your actual code, or better: A [mre] of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string ask(a)
{
```

Is not valid C++ syntax.  The error is telling you that something was expected before the `{`.

It is not clear to the compiler (or us) whether you were trying to define a **variable**

```
std::string ask(a);
```

or a **function**

```
std::string ask(std::string a)
{
```

or perhaps this **function**

```
std::string ask(std::string const &a)
{
```

or this **function** (`a` is already visible)

```
std::string ask()
{
```

Comment: Seems more likely that `ask` is meant to be a void function.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are trying to define a function `ask` which has a string parameter and returns nothing. But you got the syntax for that wrong

```
std::string ask(a)
```

should be

```
void ask(std::string a)
```

`void` is the return type of a function which doesn't return anything and `std::string` is just before the parameter name `a` which is where you should specify the type of a parameter.